# Будильник на JAVA

Tags: android, java

Я начинающий в JAVA. До этого писал на Delphi. Если у кого-то есть пример кода на Яве, буду признателен. Но самое главное, как запустить ВИБРАЦИЮ при срабатывании будильника. Это, наверное, самое главное, что нужно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы, наверное, начали программировать для мобильных устройств? А именно Android?
Я не знаю, может, у Вас в компьютере есть виброзвонок.  
Если Вы имели в виду для Андроид, тогда следует получить объект типа `Vibrator` с помощью системеного сервиса.

```
 import android.os.Vibrator; // Импорт для класса Vibrator
     Vibrator v = (Vibrator) this.context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE); // Получение объекта с помощью системного сервиса
     v.vibrate(1000); // Вибрация 1 секунду.
```

И не забудьте прописать разрешения (запрос на разрешение) в файле AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Извиняюсь за нечетко заданный вопрос, но вы сказали верно, программирую под андроид. Сейчас буду пробовать. Надеюсь, все получится.